# How can I stop the dock covering part of my application?

Tags: macbook-pro, dock, catalina

The doc covers the bottom of each application that is not maximized.

Particularly in an application like the terminal, I need to get work done in that part of my screen. As you see in the image,  my prompt, where I have typed "echo 4," is simply covered by the dock. I then have to manually resize the window just to get it out of the way of the dock.

I know I can automatically show/hide the dock, but I'd rather it was visible, yet not interfering.

[image]

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5327/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-dock-on-a-per-application-basis?rq=1 you can also minimise it and set animation for hovering.

Comment: Thank you. By "minimise it and set animation for hovering"  do you mean "Automatically hide and show" from Settings. I did that, but I would like it to be available, as can be done in  Ubuntu and Windows. (This means that the screen real estate is simply taken by the dock. Npthing can go above/below it.)

Comment: no @joshua , I meant reduce its size and use animation to magnify it when you hover over it. or get accustomed to dock on the right, (of the left for that matter, but most apps have controls on the left)

Comment: @JoshuaFox: If you open the Dock preferences (Command + Space, type in Dock, push enter), then alter the Dock to be on the left/right side of the screen, and then alter it to be back on the bottom, it will stop covering your application. Give a try.

Comment: Udhy, I  did that --same problem

Comment: anki, thank you for the link. But that is about hiding the dock and menu bar to achieve true full screen. I actually want -- when I am not in "Full Screen", and  the app is not maximized  -- to reduce my effective screen area, so that the dock is there permanently and no apps can go there.

Comment: ankii, thank you. I did make it much smaller, with animation to get bigger, but it still covers a part of any non-maximized app. Any smaller would make it hard to use. Moving it to the left or right is a good id3ea, but it still covers part of each app, and in a multiscreen setup, the dock might be way over off my main screen.

Comment: Some applications can have min window size so maybe it's not best fit for your screen.

Comment: user14492 -- what you see with Terminal is quite standard: A standard application, and a window that is not maximized but still pretty big.  Given this, I expect to be able to do normal work without the line of text being covered