# How to automatically hide/show dock depending on whether any apps are running in foreground?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, dock, automation

In GNOME (on Linux), there is an extension called "Dash to Dock", which gives you a macOS-like dock.  One very nice difference is that when you set it to automatically hide the dock, it only hides it when there are apps running in the foreground.  If you're on the desktop, the dock always shows.  As soon as you open an app, it hides.  I want this same functionality in macOS but there is no GUI option for it and I can't seem to find any way to set it programmatically or otherwise.  Can any of you offer any suggestions, or confirm that there's simply no way to do this at all?

If it matters, I'm running macOS 10.15.2 (Catalina) on a MBP mid-2012.

Comment: [Is it possible to hide the dock on a per-application basis?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5327/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-dock-on-a-per-application-basis). well it was 2009.

Comment: I suppose you could write a background app to do it, but the idea for auto-hide is to keep the dock out of the way unless you want to use it.  There is also a difference with macOS in that there is always an app running in the foreground (Finder.app is active on the desktop).

Comment: In case you want to use the info in the link of the comment from ankii, in **Terminal** use: `defaults write /path/to/name.app/Contents/Info.plist LSUIPresentationMode -int 4 `

Comment: @red_menace I know what the intent of auto-hide is and, like I said, when an app is opened it would hide but otherwise be visible when on just the desktop (which is how it behaves in GNOME). That is true, though, about Finder. I didn't consider that Finder is technically always running on the desktop.  That could be a showstopper for this topic.

Comment: @ankii I've seen that. It's not quite what I want, because I don't want to have to do it on an app-by-app basis, though I could theoretically just tell it to only be visible when Finder is in the foreground.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks.  I've seen the article before I asked my question. See my response to ankii.